# Understanding the role of layers and activation functions in Keras neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, mnist

What is the role of `(28, activation="relu"`) function, `Dropout` and `softmax` in neural network for mnist dataset need proper guidance of each layer this whole code

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])
```

Comment: I would suggest reading the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/) of Keras. Functions, and the roles of their parameters are pretty well explained there.

Answer (score 4):

The numbers 128,10 are the number of neurons in each layer of your network. tf.Dense() is used to create layers.

relu, softmax are the activation functions and these activation functions are used to provide non-linearity to the output of a neuron.

The purpose of activation functions is well described here:

https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5493/what-is-the-purpose-of-an-activation-function-in-neural-networks.

Dropout layer is used for providing regularization to network and thereby preventing your Neural network from over-fitting. To say simply, by drop-out some neurons are de-activated, so that the interdependency between specific features is removed.

See this: https://medium.com/@amarbudhiraja/https-medium-com-amarbudhiraja-learning-less-to-learn-better-dropout-in-deep-machine-learning-74334da4bfc5

Comment: and how we know that ,how much neurons would be Required in our  neural network ?

Comment: It is well explained here:https://towardsdatascience.com/beginners-ask-how-many-hidden-layers-neurons-to-use-in-artificial-neural-networks-51466afa0d3e check this article.